# How to change css styles of Google Plus Pages Badge?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one, badge

I configuring standart badge on https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config

For it Google+ rendering iframe content.
How i can change classes styles inside iframe?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it seems there is currently no way to do it. I tried editing the CSS to get rid of the annoying border and white background:

```
.yeb { 
    background-color: none !important;
    border: 0px solid gainsboro !important;
}
```

But since the CSS is in the Google server you can't override the iFrame. It is a current [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=162) in the Google forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little trick:

The HTML for the iframe:

```
<div id="social_gplus_circle">
<div id="social_gplus_circle_inner"><g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/105379671042990608528" size="smallbadge"></g:plus></div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the trick:

```
#social_gplus_circle{overflow: hidden;width: 105px;height: 45px;padding-top: 7px;}
#social_gplus_circle_inner{overflow: hidden;position: relative;top: -20px;left: -130px;height: 50px;width: 276px;}
iframe{display: block!important;}
```

I did not made this myself, I got it from a google forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it , because the google plus code is not on your server.
You can only modify the iframe CSS , if your page and the iframe code is on the same server.

Comment: However, it seems Google uses not only iframe things, but javascript append too, currently I have a problem with it, because I have predefined css for tables, and google+ button also uses it , so it's a little bit messy , some part of the "bubble" are crashed.

Comment: I know it. I ask about alternative ways of changes css-styles. Facebook like-box have it.

Comment: Yeah - because of cross-site policy, you cant do anything about it. Until google offers a way to change it. You can always add a border to the iframe, or re-size the iframe - but not modify whats inside the iframe.